# PHP Button Counter Issue

Tags: php, performance, button, reload, counter

I'm fairly new to PHP, but have managed to set up a script that simply displays the amount of times a button is clicked each time a user clicks on it.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');
flock($f, LOCK_EX);
$total = (int) fread($f, max(1, filesize('counter.txt')));
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
rewind($f);
fwrite($f, ++$total);
}
fclose($f);
?>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action='' method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="click" />
</form>
This button has been clicked <?php echo $total; ?> times.
```

The counter works and everything, but there are three issues I hope you guys can help me with:

1. The counter increases each time the page is reloaded. I only want the counter to increase when the button is clicked. Is there a way I can fix this?
2. Each time I refresh the page, Firefox asks me to confirm that I want the page to be reloaded. I know there is an option in my browser settings to prevent this, but was wondering if there was a way to refine my php so that this message does not occur for the user as well.
3. If you click the button a couple of times and then try to use the Back button, it takes you through each one of the previous clicks. Again, is there a way to fix my code so that it does not do this and instead goes to the previous page?

HUGE thanks!!

Comment: the counter will increase each time the page is refreshed as the form is being submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order:

1. It increases the counter when a POST request is made; the problem is that your script doesn't do redirection after the POST has been processed. Just a simple `header()` redirect will do. This turns the next request in a GET and voila!
2. Again, when you click the button once it will refresh the page and post your form; because your script doesn't redirect, when you reload the page Firefox (and other browsers too) will ask you for confirmation.
3. The back button behaviour can't really be changed, but you could force the browser to never cache the page (search for 'disabling browser cache php' to see what headers you have to provide).

---

```
$f = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');
flock($f, LOCK_EX);
$total = (int) fread($f, max(1, filesize('counter.txt')));
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    rewind($f);
    fwrite($f, ++$total);
    // when we're done increasing the counter
    // you will lose the POST data once the page refreshes
    // so remember to do whatever else you need to do here
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate your outlined feedback. One question, where exactly would I put header()

Comment: Hey Jack – I added header() where you specified, however it did not seem to fix it. I'm also getting an error. Can you possibly give me an example of what it should look like?

Comment: Does the error say 'cannot add header information, headers already sent'?

Comment: It says: Warning: header() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/phawre/public_html/new-php-testing/index.php on line 8

Comment: This is what I have:

<?php
$f = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');
flock($f, LOCK_EX);
$total = (int) fread($f, max(1, filesize('counter.txt')));
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   rewind($f);
   fwrite($f, ++$total);
   header();
}
fclose($f);
?>

Comment: Thanks Jack! I appreciate your help...I took a look at that link and still am not sure what I am doing wrong with my code tog et that error. Hmmmmmm

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what you do there. You have a page with php in it and a self-submitting form which in fact does nothing but reload the page. When the page is reloaded the $total counter is incremented thus, it doesn't metter if you reload the page "via form" or via brawser, the effect is the same. 
The Firefox alert behaviour is due to the presence of a form inside the html page, the brawser asks your confirm as all the input data will be lost on refresh.
As I said each click is a page reload, thus going back just brawses the multiple refreshes.

To fix all of these problems you should consider using javascript/jQuery with AJAX:

- put the $total counter handling in a separate page like counter.php
- set a button without a form to wrap it and give it an unique ID then use jQuery to bind it to a click event
- on click event perform an AJAX get call to the counter.php page and alert the request response (or prepare a span with unique id where to display the response via jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

You need to put a check, whether button was clicked or page was refreshed.

put your code under this condition

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']){
   $f = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');
   flock($f, LOCK_EX);
   $total = (int) fread($f, max(1, filesize('counter.txt')));
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      rewind($f);
      fwrite($f, ++$total);
   }
   fclose($f);
}
?>
```

Also, try to user other name for your submit button. instead of `name="submit"` try, `name="doPost"`.. helpful when accessing elements via javascript

Cheers.

Comment: He still has to read how many times the button was pressed. Check the end of his code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to look into an AJAX-based solution, using jQuery. Here's a rough sketch of how this would work (not tested). Add this to your HTML header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function call_form() { 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: PATH TO YOUR PHP SCRIPT,
    success: update_text
  });
};

function update_text(data) { 
   $('#counter').html(data);
};
</script>
```

And put this in your document body:

```
//Put some PHP code here to fetch the count at page load and put that in $initial_count
<div>
<button type="button" value="Increment counter" id="counter" onClick="call_form();" /> 
</div>

<div>
This button has been clicked 
<span id="counter"><?php echo $initial_count; ?></span> 
times.
</div>
```

Now all you need to do is update your PHP script storing new clicks (which should be in a different file) and get it to echo back the updated count.